# (SOLVED) how to enable and disable device in one batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, wmic, devcon

I want a shortcut that enable/disable a network card according to its status. I figured out how to enable or disable using either devcon, wmic and pnputil or found some Q&As here that suggest scripts that include conditional code but none of them works for me... the best I managed was to enable it when its disabled but the script doesnt disable it when its enabled...

this is one of the scripts that enable but do not disable:

```
@echo off 

wmic path Win32_PnPEntity get FormFactor|find "2" >nul && goto :disable || goto :enable
goto :eof
:disable
  wmic Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "Name='Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller'" Call Disable
  goto :eof
:enable
  wmic Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "Name='Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller'" Call enable
  goto :eof
```

and this is another one

```
@echo off 

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('devcon status *DEV_8168^|find "Device is"') do set "status=%%a"
echo status is %status%


IF "%status%" == "running" (
  devcon disable *DEV_8168
) ELSE (
  devcon enable *DEV_8168
)
```

This last one gives me a clue of a kind, when the device is disabled the status query echo %status% returns 'disabled' but when it is enabled it returns nothing rather than 'running', which I believe is what it should return

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
Thanks to io-oi reply I have a working script

```
@echo off & setlocal

pushd %__AppDir__% && 2>nul =;(
    reg.exe query HKCU\Environment /d /e /f on|find.exe /i "Click" >nul && =;(
       netsh.exe interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=Disabled
       netsh.exe interface set interface name="WiFi" admin=Enabled 
       setx.exe Click off >nul & endlocal & goto :eof                  );= || =;( 
       netsh.exe interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=Enabled
       netsh.exe interface set interface name="WiFi" admin=Disabled 
       setx.exe Click on 1>nul & endlocal & goto :eof                  );= );=
```